# Navigating back to implementation is not working in rubymine 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine-7

Rubymine: 7.0.3
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

If I want to see any methods source code **Ctrl + left mouse** or **Ctrl + B** is taking me to the source code, even it is in another file.

If I want to come back to same implemented place again, it is not coming.

I searched is many places, everyone suggesting **Ctrl + Alt + B** will take back to the implemented place.  But when I am trying to use that, it is giving me an error ***No implementations found***.

Please help me, what I need to do to get the things worked in the correct way.

Comment: What do you mean, "back to same implementation"?

Comment: From place where the method is invoked if I click Ctrl + B then it takes me to the method definition. If I wish to go back to the place where the method is invoked, the suggested solution is Ctrl + Alt + B and that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the hotkey is not set. Visit preferences and set it to whatever you like.

[image]